# Magnetic behaviour of pencil lead

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

Since graphite exhibits a diamagnetic behaviour I was expecting a pencil lead to be repelled by a magnet, but trying several times with different leads it appears to be attracted.

[image]

I was wondering about the reason: are there any impurities in pencil leads that can make them paramagnetic or even ferromagnetic? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google search pulled up [this article](https://physicsworld.com/a/physicists-pin-down-graphites-magnetism/),
which reports on [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1399) in *Nature Physics*.

The essence of it is that pure graphite is (at least mostly) diamagnetic, but the presence of defects - seven or eight membered rings, vacancies, and nontrivial domain edges - have ferromagnetic behaviour. Pencil lead is an amalgam of small, crude graphite grains and clay binder, so presumably it is defect-rich and so ferromagnetic.

Comment: ...and nothing stops the clay from containing a ferromagnetic fractions.

Answer (score -2):

"Lead" can refer to both the chemical element (Pb) and the concept of guiding or influencing others. In terms of the chemical element, lead is not inherently magnetic. It does not exhibit strong magnetic properties like iron or nickel.

However, in the context of guiding or influencing others, "lead" can be magnetic in a figurative sense. Effective leaders can attract and inspire followers through their qualities, actions, and charisma. This kind of magnetic attraction is based on leadership skills, communication, and the ability to motivate and engage others.

So, while lead (the element) is not magnetic, the concept of leadership can indeed be magnetic in a metaphorical way. [leads generate](https://aksoftco.com/)

Comment: Pencil leads don't contain lead (the metal). They contain *graphite*, an allotrope of carbon. When you move the lead across a piece of paper, planes of atoms slide off the graphite on to the paper.

Comment: As @PhilipWood said. But there are inkless pens that write with actual metal, e.g., silver, gold or lead: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2498/79678. See answers there.

Comment: Yes indeed. I believe that pencil leads are called 'leads' because they used to contain the metal lead, which will leave a mark on a surface over which it is rubbed – preferably stone.